# Using Jquery to style file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload, styling

I have a file input that I have styled to be a custom button, but i'm not able to keep the upload image when the user uploads the file.  It is replaced with the text of the file name but i would also like to keep the image.  I know it is something simple but can't seem to figure it out.  here is the code:

HTML:

```
 <div id="file"><img src="~/Images/choosefile.png" /></div>
 <input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

fileInput.change(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $('#file').text($this.val().substring(12, 75));
})

$('#file').click(function () {
    fileInput.click();
}).show();
```

CSS:

```
`#file 
{
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}​`
```

**Update - here is how it turned out if anyone would like to use it*****

HTML:

```
 <div id="file" style="margin-right:10px;"><img src="~/Images/choosefile.png" style="margin-bottom:-5px; padding-right:10px;"/><span style="border-left-width:10px;"></span></div>
 <input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

fileInput.change(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $('#file>span').text($this.val().substring(12, 75));
})

$('#file').click(function () {
    fileInput.click();
}).show();
```

CSS:

```
`#file 
{
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}​`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use .text() it is replacing your image with the value of the file input.  I recommended adding a span inside your DIV and setting the value of the current input on it.  It will be easier to separate and keep track of.

HTML

```
<div id="file"><img src="~/Images/choosefile.png" /><span></span></div>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

JQuery

```
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);
fileInput.change(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $('#file>span').text($this.val().substring(12, 75));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileInput.change(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $('#file').text($this.val().substring(12, 75));
})
```

In this code you have to change some code :

```
fileInput.change(function () {
    $this = $(this);
       $('#file').html('<img src="'+$this.val()+'" />');
})
```

Note: Make sure the image is already on that server which you are uploading from.